# How to iterate over a sequence of elements?

Tags: iteration

I want to set the foreground colours for outlines using a list stored in `pigment-darkbg`.  How can I do this in a neat and short way ?

```
(defun outline-tyface ()
  (interactive)

  (let ( (pigment-darkbg
            [ "#4fafff" "#4fe42f" "#fe6060" "#f0dd60"
              "#ff62d4" "#3fdfd0" "#fba849" "#9f80ff" ]) )

    (set-face-foreground 'outline-1 "#4fafff")
    (set-face-foreground 'outline-2 )
    (set-face-foreground 'outline-3 )
    (set-face-foreground 'outline-4 )
    (set-face-foreground 'outline-5 )
    (set-face-foreground 'outline-6 )
    (set-face-foreground 'outline-7 )
    (set-face-foreground 'outline-8 )))
```

Comment: I see no particular reason to use a vector there. In Lisp it's usually simpler and better to use lists. But if you really want to use a vector then instead of just `dolist` (as @db48x showed) you'll need to use `while` or equivalent, and use `aref` to access the iterated indexed vector element.

Comment: In a case like this, where you can tell you want to iterate, it's a good idea to get in the habit of *asking Emacs*: look for iteration in the Elisp manual: `i iteration`. And `i iteration over vector or string` tells you about `seq-doseq`, which is like `dolist` but works also for a vector or string.

Comment: @Drew: Perhaps because *vector* is faster to access and takes up fewer bytes than *list*?

Comment: I have no problem using a list instead.

Comment: @shynur: Relevant in the example? I don't expect so. It happens that people used to other languages sometimes use vectors/arrays/strings more than is common with Lisp.

Comment: Retitled and removed tag `vector`. Clearly the question isn't asking about iterating over **vectors**, if the accepted answer doesn't answer that question at all. Please try to ask whatever it is that you're really wanting to know. Please pay more attention to what you *actually ask*, wrt what you really *intend to ask*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chapter 11.5 Iteration of the Emacs Lisp Manual will tell you how to write several kinds of loops. I recommend using `dolist`. To quote from the documentation:

```
   The ‘dolist’ and ‘dotimes’ macros provide convenient ways to write
two common kinds of loops.

 -- Macro: dolist (var list [result]) body...
     This construct executes BODY once for each element of LIST, binding
     the variable VAR locally to hold the current element.  Then it
     returns the value of evaluating RESULT, or ‘nil’ if RESULT is
     omitted.  For example, here is how you could use ‘dolist’ to define
     the ‘reverse’ function:

          (defun reverse (list)
            (let (value)
              (dolist (elt list value)
                (setq value (cons elt value)))))
```

I’m sure you can take it from there.